# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (React Native (HOOKS))

Tags: api, react-native, react-hooks

Estou tentado fazer chamada a API mas esta retornando o erro de aviso:

> "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection".

Existem perguntas semelhantes, mas nenhuma especifica para react hooks pelo que vi.

Seguem os códigos

***api.js***

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001/api'
});

export default api;
```

***ReportScreen.js***

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function loadReports() {
        const response = await api.get('/reports');

        console.log(response.data);
    }

    loadReports(); 

}, []);
```

Observação: no `backend` já esta setado o `Cors` e outras dependências necessárias .

Comment: tem certeza que o erro é ai?

Comment: Por incrível que pareça sim... É o único trecho de JavaScript, o resto do código é elemento gráfico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este warning é porquê você está usando o o `await` sem um `try cacth`

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function loadReports() {

        try {
           const response = await api.get('/reports');

           console.log(response.data);

        } catch(error) {
           console.log(error)
        }

    }

    loadReports(); 

}, []);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu a warning, mas continua retornando um array vazio

Comment: Dá o console .log no erro pra compartilhar com a gente

Answer (score 1):

No seu arquivo Api.js troque para

`const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://10.0.2.2:3001/api'
});`

e caso esteja utilizando o expo

`const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://**ip do expo**:3001/api'
});`

verifique se irá resolver o erro

Comment: Na verdade funcionou trocando o baseURL, como sugeriu. Mas agora ``` console.log(response.data); ``` retorna um array vazio

Comment: Tenta verificar na sua API se está tudo funcionando direito.